# How to design the class, which will be accessed by multiple threads.

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create a class which will be accessed by multiple threads for getting a data. So I have a method like this:

```
public static String getData(){
 //some logic before returning the value
 // return data once initialized
}
```

Now there will be method which will set that data:

```
private void setData(){
}
```

I want this `setData` to be called only once, so thought of including it in `static` block:

```
static {
  setData()
}
```

Now I have these questions:

1. I'm planning to create a static class for this, so that other threads can call like this:

   `ThreadSafe.getData();`
2. In my `getData`, I want to check first the validity of that data before returning, if the data is invalid, I need to again call `setData` and then return it. Given this fact, I need to make `getData` `synchronized` right?

will my above approach work in a multi threading environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use synchronization:

```
public class ThreadSafe {

    private static final Object monitor = new Object();
    private static final String data;

    static {
        setData();
    }

    private static void setData() {         
            data = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public static String getData() {
        synchronized(monitor) {
            if (data.indexOf("7") < 0) { 
                // recalculate invalid data
                setData();
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in multiple ways.

1. You can use `volatile` variable ( If one `Thread` `write/modify` data and all `other Threads` read the data
2. You can use [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) variables ( *If multiple threads can read/modify shared data*)

If you have some atomic transaction on top of these variables instead of just write & read data, you have to protect your business transaction code block with `synchronized` or other alternatives like [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) API.

Refer to this [jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/atomicreference.html) tutorial for more details.

Related SE posts with code examples:

[Difference between volatile and synchronized in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519664/difference-between-volatile-and-synchronized-in-java)

[Avoid synchronized(this) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442564/avoid-synchronizedthis-in-java)

[When to use AtomicReference in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964211/when-to-use-atomicreference-in-java)

[What is the difference between atomic / volatile / synchronized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749746/what-is-the-difference-between-atomic-volatile-synchronized)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you better synchronise (with double lock checking) block that calls setData() in getData().  Assuming it's a rare case this should work faster on high load.

Comment: Double lock checking is borked: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/java-concurrency/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html and has been for a long time

Comment: It's not with volatile