# Re-Check mutable reference for "synchronized" lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to make a `synchronized` lock that will respond to changing references. I have code that looks something like this:

```
private void fus(){
    synchronized(someRef){
        someRef.roh();
    }
}
...
private void dah(){
    someRef = someOtherRef;
}
```

What I would like to happen is:

1. Thread A enters `fus`, and acquires a lock on `someref` as it calls `roh()`. Assume `roh` never terminates.
2. Thread B enters `fus`, begins waiting for someRef` to be free, and stays there (for now).
3. Thread C enters `dah`, and modifies `someRef`.
4. Thread B is now allowed to enter the synchronized block, as `someRef` no longer refers to the object Thread A has a lock on.

What actually happens is:

1. Thread A enters `fus`, and acquires a lock on `someref` as it calls `roh()`. Assume `roh` never terminates.
2. Thread B enters `fus`, finds the lock, and waits for it to be released (forever).
3. Thread C enters `dah`, and modifies `someRef`.
4. Thread B continues to wait, as it's no longer looking at `someref`, it's looking at the lock held by A.

Is there a way to set this up such that Thread B will either re-check the lock for changing references, or will "bounce off" into other code? (something like sychronizedOrElse?)

Comment: It sounds like you're synchronizing on the wrong object.

Comment: Is this curiosity or are you searching for a solution ?

Comment: @UDOX - Little of each. It's enough of an edge case in my code that it's not a huge concern (if the `roh`-equivalent method fails to terminate, that's probably enough of a problem on its own that my locks messing up aren't the real culprit), but it would be good to know, and it seems like it would be generally useful for avoiding deadlocks.

Comment: Re, "Assume roh never terminates."  If that is possible, then you should not be calling it from inside a `synchronized` block.  If your code ever spends as much as a millisecond (of CPU time, not real-time) in any `synchronized` block, then it's time to re-think the design.

Comment: @EdwardPeters Why would you want to change the object on which to lock? Is it to force the release of a lock by a non-responsive thread?

Comment: @jameslarge It might not make sense with `synchronized` in particular, but it is an interesting question in general.

Comment: Is this only a one-time scenario ? A(locks)->B(waits)->C(unlock B)->B(awakes) and what afterfards ? If next thread D that calls `fus` must start this scenario agaiin ?

Comment: @biziclop The initial problem had to do with multiple GUI panels, any one of which might be "visible" at a given time. The visible panel (and only the visible panel) would want to poll for updates about the status of its contents. This polling would occur on a regular basis, but also promptly when the panel came into view; the synchronization is to assure that the timer-initialized and user-initialized polls don't interleave. However, if a different panel became visible, it would be okay for its update() to be called before the prior one completed. someRef refers to the currently visible panel

Comment: @kordiko In general, yes, this expected to cycle - several threads may call `fus()` at any time, while another thread will occasionally modify `someref`.

Comment: @james large How would you handle operations that involve commands issued to a networked hub, with the requirement that those commands not interleave and the potential for high latency?

Comment: @EdwardPeters Wouldn't a queue be better suited for this kind of problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "networked hub", but if several threads in my program needed to communicate with a remote service, my first choice would be for each thread to have its own independent connection.  If I were forced to make them all share one connection, then I would add a new thread whose sole responsibility was to communicate with the remote system and, which acted as a proxy to the remote service for the other threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There surely is a way, but not with `synchronized`. Reasoning: At the point in time, where the 2nd thread enters `fus()`, the first thread holds the intrinsic lock of the object referenced by `someRef`. Important: the 2nd thread will still see `someRef` referencing on this very object and will try to acquire this lock. Later on, when the 3rd thread changes the reference `someRef`, it would have to notify the 2nd thread somehow about this event. This is not possible with `synchronized`.

To my knowledge, there is no built-in language-feature like `synchronized` to handle this kind of synchronization.

A somewhat different approach would be to either manage a [`Lock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) within your class or give `someRef` an attribute of type `Lock`. Instead of working with `lock()` you can use `tryLock()` or `tryLock(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`. This is a scheme on how I would implement this (assuming that `someRef` has a `Lock` attribute):

```
volatile SomeRef someRef = ... // important: make this volatile to deny caching
...
private void fus(){
    while (true) {
        SomeRef someRef = this.someRef;
        Lock lock = someRef.lock;
        boolean unlockNecessary = false;
        try {
            if (lock.tryLock(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) { // I have chonse this arbritrarily
                unlockNecessary = true;
                someRef.roh();
                return; // Job is done -> return. Remember: finally will still be executed.
                        // Alternatively, break; could be used to exit the loop.
            }
        } catch (InterruptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (unlockNecessary) {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
...
private void dah(){
    someRef = someOtherRef;
}
```

Now, when `someRef` is changed, the 2nd thread will see the new value of `someRef` in its next cycle and therefore will try to synchronize on the new `Lock` and succeed, if no other thread has acquired the `Lock`.

Answer (score 2):

> What actually happens is ... Thread B continues to wait, as it's no longer looking at `someref`, it's looking at the lock held by A.

That's right.  You can't write code to synchronize on a *variable*.  You can only write code to synchronize on some *object*.

Thread B found the object on which to synchronize by looking at the variable `someref`, but it only ever looks at that variable one time to find the object.  The *object* is what it locks, and until thread A releases the lock on that object, thread B is going to be stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add some more info on top of excellent answers by @`Turing85` and @`james large`.

I agree that `Thread B` continues to wait.

It's better to avoid `synchronization` for this type of program by using better lock free API.

`Atomic` variables have features that minimize synchronization and help avoid memory consistency errors.

From the code you have posted, [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) seems to be right solution for your problem.

Have a look at documentation page on [Atomic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package.

> A small toolkit of classes that support lock-free thread-safe programming on single variables. In essence, the classes in this package extend the notion of volatile values, fields, and array elements to those that also provide an atomic conditional update operation of the form:

```
boolean compareAndSet(expectedValue, updateValue);
```

One more nice post in SE related to this topic.

[When to use AtomicReference in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964211/when-to-use-atomicreference-in-java)

Sample code:

```
String initialReference = "value 1";

AtomicReference<String> someRef =
    new AtomicReference<String>(initialReference);

String newReference = "value 2";
boolean exchanged = someRef.compareAndSet(initialReference, newReference);
System.out.println("exchanged: " + exchanged);
```

Refer to this [jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/atomicreference.html) tutorial for better understanding.